# visitor/listener for loop antlr4

Tags: java, antlr4

I know my title isn't that good, please do edit it if you want. So we were given a project in one of my courses which is to make compiler/interpreter. However, we've only discussed Language Design the entire semester so I'm not very knowledgeable about the technical side. So with the little time that we have, we decided to use antlr to aid us. I was tasked to make the loops in our language. There are a lot of documents related to creating the lexer and parser but not so much on how to implement the listeners/visitors, especially on loops.

I've read the question about the while loop in antlr4 but I was hoping people could help me specifically on for loop implementation.

So here's how my grammar looks like:

```
grammar Iteration;
/*
 * PARSER RULES : ITERATION
 */
program    : (statement | forg | whileg | dowhile | foreach)+; 

statement  : declaration | assign | expression | print | standalone ;

declaration: 'int' ID ('=' expression)* ';' WS*;
assign     : ID '=' expression ';' WS* ;
forInit    : ID '=' expression WS* ;
print      : type=('print'| 'printLine') (NUMBER | ID) ';' WS*;

expression :  expression op=('*'|'/') expression #Mult
            | expression op=('+'|'-') expression #Add
            | NUMBER #Lit
            | ID #Var
            | '(' expression ')' #Paren
            ;

relational :  relational op=('==' | '!=') relational #Equal
            | relational op=('>=' | '<=') relational #Greatere 
            | relational op=('>' | '<') relational #Greater 
            | NUMBER #LitLoop
            | ID #VarLoop
            ;

standalone : ID op=('++'|'--' | '-') ';' WS* ;
varChange  : ID op=('++'|'--' | '-') WS* ;

forg       : FOR LPAREN forInit* ';' relational ';' varChange RPAREN LCURL 
statement* RCURL WS* ;
whileg     : WHILE LPAREN relational RPAREN LCURL statement* RCURL WS* ; 
dowhile    : DO LCURL statement* RCURL WHILE LPAREN relational RPAREN ';' WS* ;
foreach    : FOREACH LPAREN ID IN ID RPAREN LCURL statement RCURL WS* ;

/*
 * LEXER RULES : ITERATION
 */

FOR        : 'for' ;
WHILE      : 'while' ;
DO         : 'do' ;
FOREACH    : 'foreach' ;
IN         : 'in' ;

LPAREN     : '(' ;
RPAREN     : ')' ;
LCURL      : '{' ;
RCURL      : '}' ;

EQUAL      : '==' ;
NEQUAL     : '!=' ;
GREATER    : '>' ;
LESS       : '<' ;
GREATERE   : '>=' ;
LESSE      : '<=' ;

ID         : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NUMBER     : [0-9]+ ;
WS         : [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip ;
ADD_OP     : '+' ;
SUB_OP     : '-' ;
MULT_OP    : '*' ;
DIV_OP     : '/' ;
```

I'm currently using listeners but if visitors would be a more appropriate choice then I don't mind switching.

I'm just looking for something that could guide me in implementing loops (especially for loop), it doesn't have to be a straight up answer, anything that could point me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated! (as long as it doesn't assume that I know everything there is to know about the implementation part)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Although the title of the duplicate question says "if statements", the answer also shows how to handle loops.

Comment: thank you, highly appreciated!

Comment: No problem, blah.

Comment: Hello again, I'm not really sure whether to use a listener or a visitor. I noticed that a lot of people are using visitors (or maybe i just haven't seen enough examples). So I was hoping to get your personal opinion. Which one would you recommend I use when implementing (specifically iteration and selection statements) and why?

Comment: I'd go for a visitor for the reason I mention in the Q&A I linked to. You'd use a visitor for the entire evaluation of your script, not just for the loops.

Comment: Hello again, I'm sorry for bothering you like this but I'm in desperate need of help. Would you happen to know how to implement arrays using Visitors? or know of any link that I could use as reference? :(

Comment: when you have new questions, better create a new question on SO. Be sure to include the code/grammar of your attempt as well.

Comment: Also, in the toy language TL there is support for lists/arrays: https://github.com/bkiers/tiny-language-antlr4

Comment: hi, sorry about that, i've created a new question about the comment here it is if you'd like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586618/antlr4-array-implementation-getting-values-of-elements and I'll check the link, thank you.